# Logical/Semantic error

Tags: java, html, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make condition in which

1. If an invoice number is less than 1000, force the invoice number to 0.
2. If the month field is less than 1 or greater than 12, force the month field to 0.
3. If the day field is less than 1 or greater than 31, force the day field to 0.
4. If the year field is less than 2011 or greater than 2017, force the year field to 0.

but when I try to run it, it forces all the fields to 0 even when I put the correct value for the variable :

```
Please type your invoice number: ...1111
What month is the balance due?(Choose from 1-12)... 1
What day is the balance due?(Choose from 1-31).... 12
What year is the balance due? (Choose from 2011-2017) ....2011
Your invoice number is 0 and your balance due is on 0/0/0.
```

```java
public class Invoice
{
    private int     inNum;
    private double  balDue;
    private int     m;
    private int     d;
    private int     yy;

    public Invoice ()
    {
        super();
        setInNum(inNum);
        getInNum();
        setBalDue(balDue);
        setM(m);
        setD(d);
        setYy(yy);

    }

    public int getInNum ()
    {
        return inNum;
    }

    public void setInNum (int inNum)
    {
        if (inNum < 1000)
            this.inNum = 0;
        else
            this.inNum = inNum;
    }

    public double getBalDue ()
    {
        return balDue;
    }

    public void setBalDue (double balDue)
    {
        this.balDue = balDue;
    }

    public int getM ()
    {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM (int m)
    {
        if (m < 1 || m > 12)
            this.m = 0;
        else
            this.m = m;
    }

    public int getD ()
    {
        return d;
    }

    public void setD (int d)
    {
        if (d < 1 || d > 31)
            this.d = 0;
        else
            this.d = d;

    }

    public int getYy ()
    {
        return yy;
    }

    public void setYy (int yy)
    {
        if (yy < 2011 || yy > 2017)
            this.m = 0;
        else
            this.yy = yy;
    }

    public void displayInfo ()
    {
        int inNum;

        int m, d, yy;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please type your invoice number: ");
        inNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out
                .print("What month is the balance due?(Choose from 1-12) ");
        m = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out
                .print("What day is the balance due?(Choose from 1-31) ");
        d = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out
                .print("What year is the balance due? (Choose from 2011-2017) ");
        yy = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Your invoice number is " + getInNum()
                + " and your balance due is on " + getM() + "/" + getD()
                + "/" + getYy() + ".");

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
        invoice.displayInfo();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made all those pretty setters for the class and didn't use them!

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please type your invoice number: ");
setInNum(keyboard.nextInt());
System.out.print("What month is the balance due?(Choose from 1-12) ");
setM(keyboard.nextInt());
System.out.print("What day is the balance due?(Choose from 1-31) ");
setD(keyboard.nextInt());
System.out.print("What year is the balance due? (Choose from 2011-2017) ");
setY(keyboard.nextInt());

System.out.println("Your invoice number is " + getInNum() +  " and your balance due is on " + getM() + "/" + getD() + "/" + getYy() + ".");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is failing because your call to `displayInfo` is occurring AFTER your call to all the setter methods.  It needs to happen first, otherwise the setters don't have anything to do.

I think it's a mistake to call those setter methods in the constructor.  You need to call each one once you have the value that needs to be passed to it.

So you might have a local variable for each value that you input, which you'd then pass to the setter

```
int invoiceNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
setInNumber(invoiceNumber);
```

and so on for all the other fields.